# C++: problem when assigning a value to a string (Summary unavailable...)

Tags: c++, android-ndk

I use C++ with NDK/JNI/CMake in my Android project.

I have a struct like this:

```
struct AppSettings
{
    std::string scenedir;
    std::string outmesh;
    std::string dmname = "depth-L0";
    std::string image = "undistorted";
    std::string mask;
    std::string aabb;
}
```

Now, I want to use my struct and change the value of the string 'dmname' like this:

```
 AppSettings conf; // Line 1
 conf.dmname = "depth-L3"; // Line 2
```

Strangely, on Line 1, I see with the variables inspector that only the variable 'dmname' of my struct is written 'Summary unavailable' as you can see here:

[image]

Then, on Line 2, when I try to change the string value, I get the following crash log:

[image]

Here are the details at the 3 last steps of the crash log:

[image]

[image]
Note that __s1 = "", __s2 = "", n = 77192... have values that do not correspond to the values of the previous step that can be seen on the screenshot below:

- __p = NULL gives __s1 = ""
- __s = "depth-L3" gives __s2 = ""
- __n = 8 gives n = 77192...

[image]

I don't understand the origin of all these weird things:

1. 'Summary unavailable' for just one string of my struct
2. Weird crash
3. Crash with variables that change of value between two methods of the crash log

Any idea about the origin of these problems ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Some code. somewhere else. is overwriting memory it should not (does not own).  So the contents of part of  `AppSettings` have been overwritten.  These bugs are very hard to find.  Does the NDK build system come with a tool like Address Sanitizer ?

Comment: When you are *on* line 1, `conf` is not initialised yet so what the inspector shows is meaningless. If you are *just past* Line 1 and *on* Line 2, this is not what you are supposed to see. If you see that, the damage has already been done. Its origin can be literally anywhere.

Comment: Also the fact that `scenedir` and `outmesh` show non-empty string values right after declaring `conf` should also be a red flag to you that something is going on behind the scenes to mess up `conf`'s memory.